# Error IOException in Java while input double

Tags: java, string, while-loop, double, java.util.scanner

I got an issue when I run this code. when I put the number in this program it shown this problem.

```
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    1. See Income   2. Add Menu
    3. Delete Menu  4. Back Menu
at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.ensureOpen(StreamEncoder.java:45)
at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:152)
at java.base/java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:254)
at main.addMenu(main.java:181)
at main.adminMenu(main.java:68)
at main.AdminLogin(main.java:51)
at main.main(main.java:32)
at main.main(main.java:18)
```

the code that i create is this

```
while (true) {
            DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("0.#");
            System.out.print("Enter the " + menuName + " Price: $");
            Double menuPrice = scanOption.nextDouble();
            if (menuPrice < 0){
                System.out.println("Price can not below than 0");
            } else {
                String newMenuPrice = format.format(menuPrice).toString();
                pw.append(newMenuPrice);
                pw.append('\n');

                break;
            }
            }
        pw.close();
        pw.flush();
```

Comment: I guess you called `.close()` before you do the append action. Can you provide code snippet which you have called pw.close(); ?

Comment: oh ya. I forgot to move the pw.close(). but I still got the same problem.

Comment: @KevinJulianto can you update your code, where did you put `pw.close()`? it should be after the while loop.

Comment: @BentayeI already update the code above and new error

Comment: Please format and indent your code properly so it can be understood, including by you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You are closing `pw` inside the loop. Move.
2. You are flushing `pw`, which is redundant if you're going to close it, and wrong if you have already closed it, as you have. Remove.